# componentWillMount warning on function that setState

Tags: reactjs

I have a simple clear button in my render method

```
<Button onClick={this.clearFilters(data)}> CLEAR </Button>
```

that calls function that clears out a state

```
  clearFilters(data){
   if (!data || !this.state) {
     return;
   }

   const blankFilter = '';
    this.setState({
      filter: blankFilter });
}
```

But if I add the setState line I got a ton of warnings and it pretty well freezes up.

Warning: Cannot update during an existing state transition (such as within `render` or another component's constructor). Render methods should be a pure function of props and state; constructor side-effects are an anti-pattern, but can be moved to `componentWillMount`

How can I implement this in componentWillMount?

Comment: this is because of the infinite loop, onClick expect a function, use this: `onClick={() => this.clearFilters(data)}`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest you change this `<Button onClick={this.clearFilters(data)}> CLEAR </Button>` to `<Button onClick={()=>{this.clearFilters(data)}}> CLEAR </Button>`.
I think your button `onClick` method is trying to execute the `clearFilters` function when it's rendering thus the error

Comment: Yes....that fixed it.  Thanks

Comment: @EvilEddie please accept it as an answer then

Answer (score 0):

`this.clearFilter(data)` is being executed immediately; it's a function call. It's not happening when the user clicks.

Change it to `<Button onClick={() => this.clearFilters(data)}> CLEAR </Button>`

Furthermore, why are you wanting to do this in `componentWillMount`? Why not just set the state initially to what it is supposed to be? Something like...

```
constructor(props) {
  super(props);
  this.state = { ... };
}
```

Good luck!